# Batch crop PDF pages?

Tags: windows-7, pdf, crop

I have a PDF document containing pages which have crop marks on them. I'd like to copy these pages to another PDF without the crop marks. I'm assuming I have to crop-out the crop marks but is there any way to do this in batch rather than interactively?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install ImageMagick to create a small batch script

example.bat:

```
convert yourpdf.pdf tempfile.png
convert -crop widthxheight+xoffset+yoffset *.png
convert *.png newpdf.pdf
```

This script temporarily convert the pdf pages into a series of images.
Then crop all images (specify your width, height, x offset and y offset)
Then reassembles all pages to new pdf file.

For more information about ImageMagick:
http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php

Comment: ... and pdf with text will became much heavier pdf with images

Comment: ...non-searchable and non-text-selectable too.

Answer (score 8):

[Briss](http://sourceforge.net/projects/briss/) lets you crop the margins of a pdf.  It layers all the pages so you can visually crop them in one go.  It takes maybe 20 seconds for you to do this for a pdf e-book.  Then you can read it on the Kindle with all the original PDF formatting, but without wasting margin space.  Usually the text size is around the same or a little bit smaller than the second smallest font size on the Kindle for ebook formats.  I usually prefer it to Amazon's PDF converter service for PDF's that have images or code samples.

Answer (score 5):

K2pdfopt can do this.

> K2pdfopt optimizes the format of PDF files for viewing on small (e.g.
>   6-inch) mobile reader and smartphone screens such as the Kindle's. It
>   is meant for text-based files on a white background which may also
>   have graphics or figures. It is fully automated and can batch-process
>   PDF files. K2pdfopt works by converting each page of the PDF file to a
>   bitmap and then scanning the bitmap for viewable areas (rectangular
>   regions) and cutting and cropping these regions and assembling them
>   into multiple smaller pages without excess margins so that the viewing
>   region is maximized. Any kind of PDF file (best if it has a primarily
>   white background) can be converted. K2pdfopt works especially well on
>   two-column PDF files such as IEEE and other technical journal articles
>   (see examples below--it auto-detects two-column regions on the PDF
>   page), but even single-column files will often be significantly
>   improved and much easier to read (see examples). K2pdfopt has the
>   advantage over other PDF converters in that it fully preserves the
>   rendered PDF fonts and graphics from the original file, unlike
>   programs that convert the PDF to an e-book format. Also, because
>   k2optpdf is completely independent of language or fonts, it will work
>   equally well on documents in any language.

As an example, to optimize all pdfs in the folder K2pdfopt is located, run `k2pdfopt.exe *.pdf`.

http://www.willus.com/k2pdfopt/

Answer (score 3):

Nitro PDF worked well enough. I selected the area to crop and then applied it to all pages.

Now it would be nice to enlarge the page.

Answer (score 0):

Without needing to install anything outside of Office and Acrobat, you can make a VBA/VBS Script the loop the following cropping code:

```
Sub A4ReportCrop()

    Dim AcroApp As Acrobat.CAcroApp
    Dim Part1Document As Acrobat.CAcroPDDoc
    Dim Part2Document As Acrobat.CAcroPDDoc
    Dim numPages As Integer
    Dim rect, i

    Set AcroApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")

    Set Part1Document = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")
    Part1Document.Open "C:\Users\xyz\Desktop\20171121 IPS SPS DPS.pdf" '20171121 EXE2.pdf"
    Part1Document.OpenAVDoc "Working Doc"

    Set rect = CreateObject("AcroExch.Rect")
    rect.Top = 805
    rect.Left = 36
    rect.bottom = 500
    rect.Right = 500

    AcroApp.Show
    AcroApp.Maximize 1

    i = Part1Document.CropPages(0, 0, 0, rect)
    Debug.Print "Crop Status: " & i

    If Part1Document.Save(PDSaveFull, "C:\Users\xyz\Desktop\Temp_" & _
                        Format(Now, "YYYYMMDDHHNNSS") & ".pdf") = False Then
        MsgBox "Cannot save the modified document"
    End If

    Part1Document.Close
    AcroApp.Exit

End Sub
```

Comment: I indented your code, and split a line, for readability; please check that I didn’t damage it.